# Run command after opening a file with emacsclient

Tags: emacsclient

Is it possible to specify an argument for emacsclient to run a command in the opened file? I would like to set the editor of a program to `emacsclient -r '(search-forward-regexp "^<<<")'`.

#### Addition 1

While I can run

```
emacs file --eval '(search-forward "test")'
```

the same with `emacsclient` fails with `*ERROR*: Symbol's value as variable is void: file`. Very helpful would be an `--eval-next` so I could define and use a shell alias like

```
% alias edit-as-shell='emacsclient --eval-next "(shell-mode t)"'
% edit-as-shell ~/bin/script

% alias edit-at-end='emacsclient --eval-next "(end-of-buffer)"'
% edit-at-end file
```

Comment: I don't understand the question in the current form. do you mean that the program for editing a text file is specified within the text file behind the match for `"^<<<"`? E.g., the file contains the line `<<</usr/bin/vi` and you want the file be opened with `/usr/bin/vi`? (I chose `vi` here to demonstrate what I mean with something other than `emacs`.)

Comment: To run emacs commands on the file `file`opened by `emacsclient` after the file is loaded: `emacsclient -s my_server --eval '(progn (find-file "file") (...)(select-frame-set-input-focus (selected-frame)))'`

Comment: @HåkonHægland but this implies that I know the name of the `file` I'm opening, right? But what if I don't? E.g. I use emacsclient from [Qutebrowser](https://github.com/qutebrowser/qutebrowser) when I want to edit some lengthy texts, and the filename Qutebrowser generates is random.

Comment: Ah, nvm, I figured, Qutebrowser uses `{}` as a mark in config to show where the filename should be put, so I simply did `…(find-file "{}")…`, and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
emacsclient --eval "(with-current-buffer (window-buffer) (search-forward-regexp \"^<<<\"))"
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me: `emacsclient --eval '(with-current-buffer (window-buffer) (print "hey"))' -c /tmp/1` → `"hey" *ERROR*: Symbol’s value as variable is void: /tmp/1`.